# Why is parenting armature with automatic weight not behaving as expected?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, weight-painting

While applying parenting "*with automatic weight*" to my object, it does work as expected in some places where we can see the mesh bend:
[image]

But in some other cases it doesn't bend and breaks:
[image]

I tried going into weight paint mode where the weight isn't spread correctly:
`broken weight paint`
[image]
`fixed weight paint`
[image]

But while it helps a bit, it doesn't fix the issue:
[image]

How can I go about making the mesh bend properly?

Comment: Looks as if the arm parts of the mesh aren't actually connected to the body although they are one object. Can you share your Blend file? https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: you need join the vertex for better weight calculation, in edit mode select all mesh, press M key and select "By Distance", then, for recalculate weights, in "Weight Paint" mode, first select all bones, then on "Weights" menu press "Assign Automatic from bones", and that fix the problem.

Comment: @LeonardoCáceres That worked well thank you, you should make it an actual answer not a comment so I can select it as such

Comment: In general you could say, "automatic" weights are, well, generated automatically and what software thinks the intended behavior might be. The problem with that is, the software might have different ideas opposed to what the user wants or what looks good/correct in the end.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann You're right, I just didn't know how to fix it manually though as my attempt using weight paint wasn't sufficient